# Is there a standard file extension for MSBuild files?

Tags: msbuild

Is there a standard file extension for MSBuild files that are not project files but instead more complex build scripts?

I was thinking .msbuild.proj to avoid confusion with other .proj files (which I am aware are actually MSBuild files).

Comment: I Don't know of a "standard", but I use msbuild.xml as the name.

Comment: I'd like to add that according to the books, names "*.*proj" have special meaning to MSBuild.  I don't know if that means anything outside of its own extension mechanism, but it inspires me to just use .proj.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** In retrospect, I've updated the answer to include more conventions. Credit goes to [Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105999/sayed-ibrahim-hashimi) and others on this thread.

---

### `.proj`

A popular convention for generic use. Commonly used by a main build script.

Examples:

```
build.proj
main.proj 
company.product.build.proj
```

---

### `.targets`

`.targets` files are those which is meant to be imported into other files using the Import element. Since these files are strictly re-useable they don't actually build anything. They typically are missing the properties and item values to actually build anything.

Examples:

```
Microsoft.Common.targets
Microsoft.CSharp.targets
Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets
```

---

### `.**proj`

Language specific convention where **** represents the language short acronym.

Well-known extensions:

```
.csproj    | C#
.vbproj    | VB.NET
.vcxproj   | Visual C++
.dbproj    | Database project
.fsproj    | F#
.pyproj    | IronPython
.rbproj    | IronRuby
.wixproj   | Windows Installer XML (WiX)
.vdproj    | Visual Studio Deployment Project
.isproj    | InstallShield 
.pssproj   | PowerShell
.modelproj | Modeling project
```

---

### `.props`

[A project property sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e.aspx) used by Visual C++ projects (`.vcxproj`).

Examples:

```
Microsoft.Cl.Common.props
Microsoft.Cpp.CoreWin.props
Microsoft.Cpp.props
Microsoft.Link.Common.props
```

---

### `.tasks`

A common include file to be imported by a calling MSBuild project. Contains a list of `<UsingTask>` elements.

Examples:

```
Microsoft.Common.Tasks
MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks
```

---

### `.settings.targets`

(This is a related convention if not strictly-speaking a file extension.)

A common include file to be imported by a calling MSBuild project. Contains *"various properties related to shared utilities used during the build and deployment processes as well as any other common settings"* ([Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi, 2009](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419659.aspx#id0090116)).

Examples:

[`EntityFramework.settings.targets`](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#tools/EntityFramework.settings.targets)

[`Compiler.settings.targets`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/md/compiler/Compiler.settings.targets)

[`Library.Settings.targets`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/tools/Library.Settings.targets)

Comment: I also often use ".user" for non-source-controlled overrides (I have "*.user" in my standard .gitingore file), and conditionally import this file if it exists after the version without the ".user".  For example, if I have a `<import Project="MyProject.settings.targets" />` then I follow that line with a `<Import Project="MyProject.settings.targets.user" Condition="Exists('MyProject.settings.targets.user')" />`.  That way, if I need to override anything for the local machine but don't want it in source-control, I can put it in there.

Answer (score 15):

The closest there is to a standard is as follows:

1. .proj
2. .targets
3. .XXproj

**.targets** files are those which is meant to be imported into other files using the [Import element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx). Since these files are strictly re-useable, they don't build anything. They typically are missing the properties and item values actually to build anything.

**.proj** files are created files which can be built by themselves. They may import .targets files.

**.XXproj**, for example, .csproj or .vbproj are files which build files containing a specific language. For example .csproj is for C# projects and .vbproj for VB.NET project files. This convention comes from Visual Studio.

Comment: Sayed, do you have a source for this?  Could you post a link?

Comment: This is not really documented anywhere, but this is the convention.

Comment: Are there any open source project that could be used as references?

Comment: Umm I don't know, but I know the landscape pretty well so I would say that I'm a pretty reliable source on MSBuild (http://sedotech.com/Resources/InsideMSBuildBook).

Answer (score 5):

We just use `.build`

Comment: One could use `*.工程` to annoy tools that don't have proper Unicode support.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend what VS does:

```
.*proj for project files --- msbuild.exe will find them automatically if they match this pattern
.targets for build process --- generally imported towards the end of your project
.props for shared settings --- generally imported towards the top of your project. C++ (*.vcxproj) files use these, and they will doubtless get added to VB and C# default project files at some point.
```