# TeamCity MSBuild, remap folders during deployment

Tags: deployment, msbuild, automation, continuous-integration, teamcity

We have a solution with a website project which is hosted on a load balanced environment. At the moment no CI is being used, and deployments are manual using zip-files >_< however I'm looking on setting it up, and have run into some difficulties.
The solution requires a App_Config folder containing all the configurations for the site in the root, however these configurations differ from each of the hostingserver, where one is the management server and another is the delivery server.

Each individual server configurations is stored in a separate folder at /Configs/servername/ containing a web.config file and the App_Config folder. These have been manually copied from this folder to the root to overwrite those that already existed.
Also deployment of the /Configs/ folder is not wanted.

Preferably no changes should have to be done to the Visual Studio solution.

Is it possible to automate this before deployment in TeamCity?

regards

Comment: Are you planning to use webdeploy to publish your sites?

Comment: Yes using msbuild command to deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to set properties with different values based on the computer name.
That's one trick of the trade.

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(Computername)'=='MyManagementServer01' ">               
        <PropertyGroup>
            <MyCustomProperty001>Red</MyCustomProperty001>
            <MyCustomProperty002>Yellow</MyCustomProperty002>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </When>

    <When Condition=" '$(Computername)'=='MyDeliveryServer01' ">

        <PropertyGroup>
            <MyCustomProperty001>Black</MyCustomProperty001>
            <MyCustomProperty002>White</MyCustomProperty002>
        </PropertyGroup>

    </When>

    <Otherwise>

        <PropertyGroup>
            <MyCustomProperty001>NoMatchMyCustomProperty001</MyCustomProperty001>
            <MyCustomProperty002>NoMatchMyCustomProperty002</MyCustomProperty002>
        </PropertyGroup>        

    </Otherwise>

</Choose>
```

You could setup a property called

```
<ConfigurationSourceFolder>/Configs/MyManagementServer01/</ConfigurationSourceFolder>
```

Or setup a "DeploymentType"

```
<DeploymentType>ManagementServerType</DeploymentType>
```

You can also put Conditions on "Targets" and even Tasks.

```
<MakeDir Directories="C:\MyCoolDirectory" Condition="('$(MyCustomProperty001)'!='')"/>
```

//////Preferably no changes should have to be done to the Visual Studio solution.//////

So here is an "in-general" tip.
Instead of putting alot of custom sometimes-hard-to-follow changes in the csproj files....use a basic .msbuild file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapped">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Always declare some kind of "base directory" and then work off of that in the majority of cases  -->
        <WorkingCheckout>.</WorkingCheckout>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapped">

        <CallTarget Targets="BuildItUp" />

    </Target>


    <Target Name="BuildItUp" >
        <MSBuild Projects="$(WorkingCheckout)\MySolution.sln" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
            <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="TargetOutputsItemName"/>
        </MSBuild>
        <Message Text="BuildItUp completed" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: Are these changes done in the project file for the website in my visual studio solution? Or how does this work?

Comment: I would create a basic .msbuild (or .xml file) to call the main .sln build.  Let me append my answer.    A basic msbuild "holder" will serve you well IMHO.  Give me a sec.

Comment: Put the bottom most code in a file called MySolution.msbuild.  And then have TeamCity (or whatever "wrapper" CI you have) call that.  As in  "MsBuild.exe MySolution.msbuild" .. Something like that.

Comment: GranadaCoder, some good suggestions regarding the ".msbuild" file naming conventions when managing MsBuild artifacts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007689/is-there-a-standard-file-extension-for-msbuild-files

Comment: Ok.  Most of mine are ".xml", but the standard suggestions make sense.  Thanks.

Comment: I've managed to create a custom build file now which is compiling the solution, afterwards I want to move a folder to another location and overwriting all files? and finally create a package and deply to a server. How do I do that? I've tried to search for it, but I honestly don't know what to search for.

Comment: Managed to get things working. Only question left is how to create a deployment package based on files in a folder.

Comment: What is your definition of a deployment-package?  (Mine is a .zip file) and I use some MsBuild Zip Tasks.

Comment: I'm looking on creating a deployment package that I can send to web deploy service which in turn will "install" it on the desired IIS website.